# How to decide the order of limits of $u$ and $v$ in the $u-v$ plane

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Evaluate $\iint_{R} 2 y-8 x d A$ where $R$ is the region formed by the quadrilateral with vertices
$(6,0),(8,4),(6,8) \text { and }(4,4)$.

My try:
The region is a parallelogram bounded by $2x+y=12$,$2x+y=20$,$2x-y=4$ and $2x-y=12$
Now i used the transformation as:
$$2x+y=u, 2x-y=v$$
$\implies$
$$x=\frac{u+v}{4}. y=\frac{u-v}{2}$$
Now the integral is:
$$\iint_{R}(2y-8x)dA=\iint_{R^*}(-u-3v)|J|\:dudv$$

Now should i choose $u$ goes from $12$ to $20$ and $v$ goes from $4$ to $12$?

In that case i am getting answer as $-640$?

But volume cannot be negative?

So how should we choose the range of values taken by $u$ and $v$?

Comment: Are you saying integrals can never be negative? Your limits are correct btw

Comment: ya double integral represents volume right?can it be negative?

Comment: Single integrals represent area, but $$\int_0^1 -x\:dx$$ is certainly negative